# Is it OK to downvote questions asking about how to achieve something, without having posted code?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, voting

In these type of questions, users only upload some image, and then ask how to create or develop this type of UI or code.

Here is the question that the user posted:

> #### How to get an view like the below image in Android?
>
> [image]
>
> How to create an android UI like the image given below?
>
> Which will be working on the swipe gesture.

So is it OK to downvote these type of questions?

Comment: My opinion: It's borderline. Just the image might not be enough but there is actually not much missing to make it a question suitable for SO. A bit of research or if this does not give anything just fake research. Obviously if you already know how to do it you wouldn't need to ask the question. Just add 2-3 sentences about some crazy ideas that do not work and specify a bit more in your own words what the effect should be. Voila. Valid question.

Comment: @MD I think Trilarion is correct. By showing effort in valuating options a question becomes valid.

Comment: The example you have taken, that's pretty interesting, can you post a link to that question? I'd like to see of there's a good answer to that question. If it does, i'd like to implement it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes.

The downvote arrow has the following tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

I think just posting an image and asking "how do I create this" is covered by that.

If you have enough reputation it's also a good idea to vote to close (probably as "Too broad" or perhaps "It's unclear what you are asking").

Comment: Rather "too broad": There are myriad ways, and doing so in good SO quality with proper explanation needs far too much space.

Comment: No, close as "too broad". In this case, it's clear what OP wants and it's clear he has no idea how to start, so it's definitely too broad.

Comment: @l4mpi I thought down vote this type of questions with close vote ("It's unclear what you are asking")

Comment: @MD It's totally clear what he wants, so that's not a good close reason.  "Too broad" works, though

Comment: Though I don't encourage bad questions, sometimes if its easy enough to point someone in the right direction, I just answer it.

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking whether there is a particular library to achieve that effect.

Comment: @JohnPeyton - in that case the question should be closed as a shopping request.

Comment: @logixologist - except that DOES encourage bad questions. If questions get answers because it's "easy" even if they're bad, you're implicitly telling future askers of bad questions that their questions will probably get answers too.

Comment: Yeah. I see your point too , however I have found answers to things I have needed when people asked a bad question. Different choice of words they used helped me find it.

Comment: I this question really too broad? There cannot be that many good ways to achieve the desired outcome, can there?

Comment: @Trilarion The close reason isn't just for "too many ways", it also includes the text "or good answers would be too long for this format"

Comment: What if the user really, really has no idea what he's doing and just wants to be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: @Bluefire - then they need to ask in chat or somewhere else, it's not a suitable question for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: @Bluefire then they're in the wrong place

Comment: @Bluefire User has all idea what he asking about but he dont know how to start?

Comment: @Bluefire some guidance from another Stack Exchange's meta: [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6366/40980)

Comment: @lzkata Okay but would answers to such a fairly specific UI element have been too long for this format? Although answers usually are short (2-10 lines long) I frequently encounter very long and detailed answers >100 lines and they usually are upvoted to heaven.

Comment: *it also includes the text "or good answers would be too long for this format"* @Izkata - I wish I could up vote this multiple times; I think people forget this part.

Answer (score 18):

**No**(t always).

The downvote arrow has the following tooltip:

```
This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
```

I don't think this is *always* the case when no code is posted.

Arguments for not down voting:

- You could show some research effort without posting code. Like ChrisF commented you could at least explain where you tried to find solutions.
- Sometimes it's difficult to know where to start, for example when you don't know the name of a feature. Therefore requiring some code will only produce some unrelated snippets.
- There are already such questions with a lot of upvotes, so it's difficult to explain to a new user why his question is invalid. In fact that would be pretty random.

  - [How does the algorithm to color the song list in iTunes 11 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13637892/199048) 230 upvotes
  - [iOS 7's blurred overlay effect using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17034485/199048) 86 upvotes

So downvoting only because there is no code is too strict, you should take the explanations into account.

Comment: You're also right..

Comment: You should be able to say "I've tried X, Y and Z to no effect" or "I've looked *here* and *there* but can't find the answer". Also, it's not always a good idea to highlight older questions as a justification for asking a poor quality question now. All that might happen is that the older questions get closed as well.

Comment: @ChrisF: I agree with that, but the question was about questions _without code_.

Comment: @Chris - You still should have done *some* research or *attempted* some coding yourself before asking so should have something to post other than the screen shot. If I'd seen the examples you quote I would have probably voted to close (it's a little late now). However, the CSS one is asking something more specific and narrower than the example in the question so that's not so bad.

Comment: @ChrisF: Again I agree with you, but your answer didn't made any exceptions, so I felt the need to create a more balanced one.

Comment: Agreed in that I'd rather see no code with some other indicators of research/effort (e.g. "I know how to do <related thing> but reading through the documentation doesn't make it clear if it can be used for <specific case>) than a huge dump of vaguely related code.

Answer (score 5):

No, but it's definitely a judgement call.

It seems to me that the question should be answered at the same technical level as the question. So in this case a question with a screen shot (that the questioner obviously put some effort into creating) probably should NOT be answered with a code block anyway. It should be answered with information that will lead the questioner to be able to ask his or her next, more specific, question. Appropriate answers might be:

- links to libraries that have this functionality
- links to the API documentation that describe customized menus (or whatever Android uses)
- links to tutorials
- Most importantly, the answer can give the questioner the domain specific terminology that will allow them (and everyone who reads the answer in the future) to efficiently search for better answers.

In my opinion, that last bullet is the most important. In essence the question is "What IS this thing?" and the best answers help the community agree on a common terminology. Sometimes that's more important than code.

Answer (score 2):

well i would know the answer on this question (use LMT). From the image it is quite clear what op wanted to achieve but how he asked showed a bit of laziness. Perhaps he should have stated what the important parts are for him (custom action from his app). If i had to answer this question i would have to ask too many questions to give a good answer which is sad because the topic is great and LMT has a lot of possibilites user know little about. So yeah downvote

Comment: thnx for your opinion...

Answer (score -5):

As down arrow showing tool tip message
*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* .People asking question without any efforts for that they should check below links as a comment

[Comment 1](http://goo.gl/AV41bX)

[Comment 2](http://goo.gl/nBxsE3)