# How in the heck is this too broad?

Tags: support, needs-more-focus

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565062/how-to-create-a-lock-screen-notification-with-image-in-swift

I just don't get it!

Comment: It looks like a pretty broad question for me, without showing any attempts or research efforts from your side.

Comment: Related: [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What attempts or research was I supposed to show here? I stated that I'm just learning Swift, and so my knowledge about the iOS api is limited. I've been searching documentation and google but came up short. That's why I asked the question on SO. What gives?!

Comment: Did you make any attempts at solving the problem? if so, show them. If not, why not? "because i'm learning" isn't good nuff.

Comment: My attempt to solve the problem was searching google and apple's docs to see if and how the api works. I didn't find anything, but that could be a result of being new to the language/framework and hence not using the correct vocabulary. How am I supposed to show these attempts?

Comment: explain the thought process. "I started by researching how to create a lock screen notification but was unable to find any examples"

Comment: There.. just updated the question. But frankly, I think the diff between the original question and what is there now is minuscule -- and reasons to close it are nitty picky.

Comment: @KevinB That's not the reason it was closed. Plus, it's not the same thing. I'm not talking about a custom alarm-type notification, but an image with a notification similar to an SMS with image.

Comment: right, i'm just trying to be helpful. It at least points you in the direction of `UIAlertController` and `UINotificationController` which is where I would begin researching after finding that question. If what you're trying to do falls outside what is possible with those two things, then it likely is a dupe in that what you are trying to do simply isn't possible.

Comment: "There is no answer" makes a question unpopular.

Comment: @KevinB well, thanks but it seems like the dimension of knit-pickery on SO is so high, that efforts to try to "help" turn into wasted time in pursuit of some "perfect question" rather than just answering someone's question and getting on with this things. It's just annoying at times.

Comment: @HansPassant There was an answer, and I selected it. It was perfectly appropriate.

Comment: I should point out that your extremely abusive comments toward another user there (now deleted) only acted to bring negative attention to that question. If someone thinks there's a problem with your question, keep calm and try to listen to them instead of insulting them.

Comment: @Nathan I think it boils down to wasted time. If you ask a question that looks interesting via the title but turns out to be a "Do my research" question, it's not going to be well received because you're wasting the time of those who thought it was interesting. With just a quick search i was able to find two components that could be useful in your task, but you didn't even mention either of them in your question.

Comment: I would have phrased the question this way: "I need to create a custom lock screen notification with an image. I've found these two components <insert docs link>, but can't figure out how to use them to create the result i want. Here's an example of the output i'm looking for. <insert image.>." Including all of this information forms a clear picture proving that you did your research.

Comment: @BradLarson abusive is in the eye of the beholder. Someone using a snide, condescending tone has the same abusive effect (if not greater due to its indirect form) to that of a direct insult. Just because it's legal to be an arrogant schmuck doesn't make it ethical.

Comment: @Nathan - In the eye of *this* beholder, a comment of "What the fuck do you think I'm doing here asshole!? Research. Jesus christ! Why does the world have to include schmucks like you!?" is completely uncalled-for in any context.

Comment: @BradLarson That's your opinion. I think it's colorful language that adds emphasis to the point that the guy was prodding me with smug, self-righteousness. Few other things that piss me off more than that and so I expressed just those emotions.

Comment: @Nathan There's a big difference between using swears/curses to emphasize a point and what you're doing.

Comment: _@Nathan_ No, it's not @Brad ' s opinion. We have policies here.

Comment: Those policies are nevertheless opinions.

Comment: ....which you are expected to follow. Just because you're upset doesn't mean you get to ignore the rules.

Comment: @Nathan _"Those policies are nevertheless opinions."_ May be. But these are currently agreed commonly now. Also laws could be called opinions, that doesn't allow to break them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Laws and ethics are not the same thing. Someone acts unethically, they should get an earful IMO.

Comment: @Nathan - What I'm trying to say is that it can be difficult to convey tone in comments, particularly if English is not your native language. luk2302 was trying to state that they didn't think it was possible for a third-party service to provide such a notification. Could they have phrased that better? Yes, but when you lashed out at them it caused people to look at your question in a very negative light and was a contributing factor to it getting closed. Had you objectively responded to the points they brought up, I don't think we'd be having this conversation.

Comment: @Nathan We have a [Be Nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy that we expect everyone to abide by. It specifically states "Don't be a Jerk", if you can't follow this or respond without being a jerk, then you should probably take a walk and get some fresh air.

Comment: @Nathan So are you trying to say the rules shouldn't apply to you? You are being extremely stubborn and obtuse. When you create a question like this on meta, people assume you want input on how to improve your question. You've spent the entire time bickering over every point anyone has tried to make here. Somehow you've even managed to take issue with the suggestion that you *not* call people "asshole" and "schmuck".

Comment: @BradLarson thanks for the clarification, but based on your analysis, users who found my comments offensive applied a possibly ill-fitting reason to close my OP due to feeling offended by comments that were tangential at best. But anyway, I get it... society at large behaves the same way. One can be a smug unethical jerk as much as they like, so long as they don't cross the line and use curse words.

Comment: @tnw Actually I don't think the rules should not apply to me. I guess as this discussion has progressed, I've shared my thoughts on what has been shared with me. Overall, my impression is the current policies and perhaps the commenting functionality in its current state is flawed. If luk2302 wasn't able to leave a smug comment, but was forced to risk offering an answer, then my exchange with him would not take place. Or, if SO policies had more precision to prevent that sort of negative condescension... I wouldn't have responded the way I did. But I would opt for less policing.

Comment: How can you be in favor of less policing all while calling for these apparently smug comments to be against the rules? You're saying calling someone an "asshole" and a "schmuck" is perfectly okay but smug commentary is not. Have you simply considered not throwing a tantrum when you get offended by a comment? This is what mature adults do, I highly recommend this rather than asking for the rules and policies to be changed to suit you.

Comment: @tnw To be clear, my preference is that either let people be rude or not. But don't pick and choose what flavor of rudeness you're willing to stand behind. You really want to live in a world where snide, underhanded comments go rewarded while colorful language used out of frustration to point out the former go punished? Sorry bro, but if that's considered being a mature adult, I'm not interested.

Comment: @Nathan if someone is insulting, flag the comment, move away. Simple. Don't respond in kind, and don't escalate the issue

Comment: @Patrice thanks, didn't know I could flag someone for that, and didn't know luk2302's comments violated the Be Nice policy.

Comment: @Nathan np. And also (since my previous comment seemed to have been flagged enough to be deleted, which is fair), there is one thing you seem to be misunderstanding about SO. When you say efforts to help are less important than the "perfect" question.... you are right, in a way. Stack is meant to help FUTURE visitors, not just you. With that goal in mind, it decided to get the best Q&A pairs to provide help to the NEXT guy coming in. The fact the OP gets help is tangential to that. The goal should ALWAYS be the quality of the repository of knowledge that is SO.

Comment: @Nathan Nobody said their comments were against any policies and it's not like they were "rewarded" either. Additionally, yours were simply removed, that's hardly a punishment. You are acting like you're a victim while everything that's happened is entirely a result of your complete inability to accept criticism of any shape or form.

Comment: @tnw "Nobody said their comments were against any policies" -- I'm not sure what you mean here. When I read the Be Nice policies I interpreted them to mean that being smug and condescending is not acceptable. You seem to be arguing the case that there are policies against "vulgar" language and all else that I'm bringing up is irrelevant since I used said vulgar language. If that's your interpretation of Stack policies, I disagree with you. If that's in fact objectively what Stack policies are, then I disagree with you both. And btw, you're acting like a self-righteous jerk -- feel better?

Comment: @tnw "it's not like they were "rewarded" either. Additionally, yours were simply removed, that's hardly a punishment"  -- in a system where information is elevated or removed, I'd say removing my comment was in fact punishment. You're just defending arrogance and smuggery, and you'll never convince me that it's ok to do that; or even that it's ethically more appropriate behavior than vulgar language.

Comment: Sigh. There is no getting through to you. You are reading my commentary and constructing a dialogue in which you are incapable of doing any wrong. Good luck with that.

Comment: Of course you would think that. In your mind you're right.

Comment: Your question is answered at [Show an image in the alert body of a local notification](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4941949) There's also [How to set the image for local notifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6407704)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Shame so much hassle had to go into getting at the information.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to downvote questions asking about how to achieve something, without having posted code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha/266385)

Answer (score 25):

> I'm just learning Swift...

That's fine, but it doesn't really matter to us. It's ok to be just starting out, but that's not information that's really helpful to people answering questions. You can leave it out.

> ...and would like to create a notification for the lock screen that includes an image -- similar to what appears when someone sends an image via SMS.

That part is good. This is what you are trying to do.

> I started by researching how to create a lock screen notification but was unable to find any examples.

This is not good. You do need to show what you've done, but this isn't nearly enough. Just searching Google isn't really enough effort, but you've also failed to tell us what you searched for. Again, people answering questions can't really do anything with this information.

> Is it possible to do this, and if so, can someone point me to any resources that could help?

This is no good, either. Questions asking for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic.

To sum up, your question is definitely too broad, as you've barely explained what problem you're trying to solve, much less *what* you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 18):

Here's why it's too broad:

- There are likely a lot of ways or approaches to create this lock screen
- You do not describe any of your attempts, nor do you make the efforts that you've taken to accomplish this public
- There's no bound to the problem; any answer that solves the problem would do and there's nothing to indicate that one answer can be more correct than another

If you're just learning the language, I would ***strongly*** encourage you to crawl before driving.  Start with the basics and build up from there.